# How to compare 2 folders content byte by byte

Tags: file-io, comparison

I need an application that will compare the content of 2 folders byte by byte. This application will be used by a tester, so it would be good if this application has a GUI.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've heard good things about this, http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/11/in-praise-of-beyond-compare.html

Comment: @Johnsyweb, thanks a lot, I was looking for this kind of tool for a weeks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Akmal, I'm using [TreeComp](http://lploeger.home.xs4all.nl/TreeComp3.htm) utility.

This is freeware tool for Windows.